# TomCat - Constructor threw exception when trying to read from File

Tags: java, tomcat

I have some methods below and basically my issue is when I try to read from a `.txt` file. The application works fine in memory. When I add the `decode()` to the overloaded constructor I get the following error in Tomcat Server logs:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

When I look more at this it points to this line in the decode method
`currentDVD.setDvdId(Integer.parseInt((currentTokens[0])));` but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. At one point I was able to read from the file and then I was trying to get the encode method to work and something happened at some point. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class DvdLibraryInFileImpl implements DvdLibraryDao {

    private Map<Integer, DVD> dvdMap = new HashMap<>();
    public static final String DVD_FILE = "dvd.txt";
    public static final String DELIMITER = "::";
    private static int dvdIdCounter = 0;

    public DvdLibraryInFileImpl() throws FileNotFoundException {
      decode();

    }


    @Override
    public DVD addDVD(DVD dvd) {

        dvd.setDvdId(dvdIdCounter);

        dvdIdCounter++;

        dvdMap.put(dvd.getDvdId(), dvd);

        return dvd;
    }

    @Override
    public DVD getDVDById(int dvdId) {
        return dvdMap.get(dvdId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<DVD> getAllDVDSByName(String searchByName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }

    @Override
    public List<DVD> getAllDVDS() {
        List<DVD> allDVDS = new ArrayList<>(dvdMap.values());
        return allDVDS;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDVD(DVD dvd) {
        dvdMap.put(dvd.getDvdId(), dvd);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeDVD(int dvdId) {
        dvdMap.remove(dvdId);
    }


    @Override
    public void decode() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DVD_FILE)));
        String[] currentTokens;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String currentLine = sc.nextLine();
            currentTokens = currentLine.split(DELIMITER);

            DVD currentDVD = new DVD();

            currentDVD.setDvdId(Integer.parseInt((currentTokens[0])));
            currentDVD.setTitle(currentTokens[1]);
            currentDVD.setReleaseDate(currentTokens[2]);
            currentDVD.setMpaaRating(currentTokens[3]);
            currentDVD.setDirectorsName(currentTokens[4]);
            currentDVD.setStudio(currentTokens[5]);
            currentDVD.setUserRating(currentTokens[6]);

            dvdMap.put(Integer.parseInt((currentTokens[0])), currentDVD);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void encode() throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(DVD_FILE));
        Set<Integer> keySet = dvdMap.keySet();
        for (Integer i : keySet) {

            out.print((dvdMap.get(i)).getDvdId());
            out.print(DELIMITER);

            out.print((dvdMap.get(i)).getTitle());
            out.print(DELIMITER);

            out.print((dvdMap.get(i)).getReleaseDate());
            out.print(DELIMITER);

            out.print((dvdMap.get(i)).getMpaaRating());
            out.print(DELIMITER);

            out.print((dvdMap.get(i)).getDirectorsName());
            out.print(DELIMITER);

            out.print((dvdMap.get(i)).getStudio());
            out.print(DELIMITER);

            out.print((dvdMap.get(i)).getUserRating());
            out.println("");

        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: This happens because `currentTokens[0]` is an empty String, so you can reduce the problem to:

    `Integer.parseInt("");`

and you will get the same result.

In its internal implementation, `parseInt` checks if that `String` has at least one character, and if it hasn't:

    `throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);`

Check the values of `currentLine` and `currentTokens`:

    `currentTokens = currentLine.split(DELIMITER);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because `currentLine` does NOT have the proper input data received (from user entry).

You should ensure that `currentTokens` is having proper DvdId set (should be numeric value), otherwise `Integer.parseInt((currentTokens[0]))` line will throw `NumberFormatException` for non-numeric or empty ("") data.

You need to ensure that the input data entered is correct with numeric `dvdid`.

For example, enter below data:
1234::DVDTITLE::29-OCT-2016::RATING1::DIRECTOR::STUDIO::RATING2

I strongly recommend you to add the input validations to handle the scenarios like entering the non-numeric values or rating higher that max value or director name containg numeric values, etc....

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have dvdId set as an int in my DTO. When I look at my dvd.txt file I have it setup as the example like you have so I would assume that it would read the dvdId as 1, 2, 3, etc for each DVD I have in my file. This is the first time I am using Tomcat to deploy my application instead of using the console in NetBeans so I am confused where my input will come from since I can't even deploy the web application with decode in the constructor. My next step is to get some validations in there. I have some for in in-memory implementation on the server side.